# customizing Navigation Drawler

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello i have such layout and i don`t understand how to add static header with photo and text 
to  Navigation Drawler. Any example? Thanks

like this one 
[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#9d9d9d"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#252525" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not as simple as *user665* suggests. If you're going straight off the example provided by Google, you need to let the `DrawerLayout` know what its content is by changing `DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen` and `DrawerLayout.closeDrawer` to the `View` your `ListView` is wrapped in, otherwise you're going to throw a `ClassCastException` because the `LayoutParams` won't match up.

So, to make a static header, you could do somehting like:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then reference `R.id.drawer_content` when using the methods I listed above.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

After the FrameLayout, the first view will accepted as Navigation Drawer, so you create a layout after FrameLayout, then put your Views inside of it. Here is a example, it is very basic but you will get the point.

```
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->


<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <RelativeLayout   
        android:id="@+id/NavDrawerInfo"      
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:id="@+id/userImage"
           android:layout_width="200dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"/>
        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/userName"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="100dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
             android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/userImage"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="100dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
             android:textSize="20sp"
            />



 </RelativeLayout>
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:childDivider="@color/list_divider"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:gravity="start" 
        android:background="#f1f1f1"/>


</LinearLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```